# Simplify a circuit

Tags: resistance, serial, parallel

[image: apologies for poor quality]

I need to calculate the total resistance of these 4 circuit parts from `a` to `b`.

Every resistor is R = 10 Ω.

My question is how do I figure out what is connected serially and what is parallel in these tasks?

Comment: You need to show some effort on this. Start with (d). There are two Rs quite obviously in parallel. Post your attempts in the question. You can use the CircuitLab tool on the editor toolbar. Show each step.

Comment: Here's another, https://tinyurl.com/yhufhmsy

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework without own attempt.

Answer (score 5):

Redraw the schematics so that it becomes more clear. These types of problems are deliberately drawn in a non-standard way to try to get you to think about connections (nodes) and how they relate to current flow and components.

To redraw any of these, start by assigning every component a designator (R1, R2, R3, etc.). Then you can redraw it in a way that makes sense to you, and keep track of the number of connections at any given node.

For example, on the leftmost schematic, I redrew it by keeping track of which end of each component connects to others. The thought process is akin to: "Okay, `a` connects to both the *left* side of R1 and the node shared by R2 and R3." Continuing to look at the original and your re-creation, you can refine the new version repeatedly until you hopefully have placed components into a more obvious arrangement.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqBgJD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The key is to assign the components numbers and realize that the *layout* of the original is unimportant — the *connections* are.

Answer (score 0):

To know the Series connection:
See the current flow through each component and the path connecting the various components.
Here for series connection, the current flow through each component is the “same”, also the components are connected along a “Single path”.For eg.the current flow through one resistor is equal to the current flowing through the other resistor.

To know the Parallel connection:
See the voltage across each component and the path connecting the various components.
For Parallel connection, the voltage across each component is “equal to” the voltage across the network.Here, the components are connected along “Multiple paths.”